# How to realize this XAML interface with Expanders and Scroolbar?

Tags: c#, xaml

I would like to realize this interface in XAML :

Initial window : https://static.oc-static.com/prod/courses/files/creez-votre-premiere-application-connectee-en-c-net/acti4_image1.png

Developed window : https://static.oc-static.com/prod/courses/files/creez-votre-premiere-application-connectee-en-c-net/acti4_image7.png

Here is what i tried :

```
       <Window x:Class="OC_GestionUtilisateurs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OC_GestionUtilisateurs"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:FicheUtilisateurViewModel></local:FicheUtilisateurViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center">
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch">
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center">
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!-- Pour éviter d'écrire du code métier dans le code de l'application, l'événement Button_Click du bouton est remplacé-->
        <Button Content="Ajout d'un utilisateur" Command="{Binding AjouterUneFicheUtilisateur}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Button Content="Supprimer l'utilisateur" Command="{Binding SupprimerUneFicheUtilisateur}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=listeDeFichesUtilisateurs, Path=SelectedItem}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <Button Content="Remise à zéro de l'utilisateur" Command="{Binding RemiseAZeroDeLaFicheSelectionnee}" CommandParameter="{Binding FicheSelectionnee}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>

        <!-- LISTE DES UTILISATEURS -->
        <!-- liaison de la propriété fiche de notre view model à notre source de données d'une listebox nous permettant d'afficher toutes les fiches utilisateurs -->
        <StackPanel x:Name="ListeUtilisateurs" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Label Content="Liste des utilisateurs" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ListBox x:Name="listeDeFichesUtilisateurs" ItemsSource="{Binding Fiches}" SelectedItem="{Binding FicheSelectionnee}" Margin="0,0,30,0">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- Présentation d'un utilisateur dans la liste -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="- "></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Nom}"></Label>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Prenom}"></Label>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>    
        <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" ExpandDirection="Left" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel x:Name="DetailUtilisateur">
                <!-- DETAIL DE L'UTILISATEUR -->
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="Détail de l'utilisateur" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>

                    <Label Content="Nom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
                    <Label Content="Prénom"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                    <Label Content="Age" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  />
                    <Label Content="Genre"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"  />
                    <Label Content="Profession" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />

                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Nom, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Prenom, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Age, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Genre, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"></TextBox>
                    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Profession, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"></TextBox>

                    <Expander HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="6" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" ExpandDirection="Down">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="AdresseUtilisateur">

                            <Grid>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- ADRESSE DE L'UTILISATEUR -->
                                <Label Content="Adresse de l'utilisateur" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"/>

                                <Label Content="Numéro" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Label Content="Rue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
                                <Label Content="Code postal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"/>
                                <Label Content="Ville" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
                                <Label Content="Pays" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5"/>

                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.NumeroRue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Rue, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.CodePostal, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Ville, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4"></TextBox>
                                <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding FicheSelectionnee.Pays, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5"></TextBox>
                            </Grid>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Expander>

                </Grid>

            </StackPanel>

        </Expander>   

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

The problem i have is that the right column width doesn't reduce when the expander isn't opened. And then, I'm not sure it is possible to put a grid inside a grid to arrange the labels and textbox inside the stackpanel  in the expanders.

What do you suggest to me?

Comment: It is possible to put a `Grid` inside a `Grid`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I updated my code. I still have the problem of reserved space for the content of my main expander in the third column. What should i try to solve it? Morever my expanders don't look the same as on the pictures i posted, and the property HorizontalAlignement="Left" doesn't seem to work :/ I don't understand why i have to put my labels in the row 1 and my textboxes in the row 0 in order to have the labels on the left of the textboxes. The opposite would have been more logical for me. If you have any suggestion to make my interface better, don't hesitate ;)